# Matrix multiplication (fractions)

Tags: java, matrix, fractions

Hi im currently creating a java program for matrix multplication with fractions, I already create a class Fraction, code below.

```
public Fraccion (int n,int m){
    numerador = n;
    denominador = m;
}
```

which receives numerator and denominator, in my main function i receive the size of the matrix, to create the matrix 2x2 3x3 and so on...
and Im currently getting the expected output.
my problem is for multiplicating the matrix by itself, (because that´s what I want)

so this is my code for the Main class

```
private static void transicion()
{
    //size of matriz
    Fraccion[][] tmp = new Fraccion[cuantos][cuantos];
    //cloning the matrix to a temporal matrix
    tmp = matrix.clone();
    //set boundaries for matrix so dont go out of bounds
    int rowLimit = matrix.length;
    int colLimit = matrix[0].length;

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++)
        {
            //method to multiply a fraction with another (producto_con)
            if ((j+1<colLimit) && (matrix[i][j] == matrix[i][j+1]))
                matrix[i][j].producto_con(tmp[i][j+1]);
            if ((i+1<rowLimit) && (matrix[i][j] == matrix[i+1][j]))
                matrix[i][j].producto_con(tmp[i][j+1]);
            System.out.println();
            matrix[i][j].imprimete();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
//this is the method to multiply fractions on the fraction class
public Fraccion producto_con(Fraccion laOtra){
    int numTmp, denTmp;
    numTmp = numerator * laOtra.getnumerator();
    denTmp = denominator * laOtra.getdenominator();
    Fraccion laNueva = new Fraccion(numTmp,denTmp);
    return laNueva;
}
```

but when I print the method transicion, prints the same matrix with no changes, any help or advice please?

Comment: but you never use the  `return laNueva;` value ?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new `Fraccion` objects but then not assigning them to anything.  So ... of course ... nothing changes.

A more insidious problem is that your numerator and denominator are stored as `int` values, and you have nothing to deal with the possibility that one or the other may overflow.  If that happens, you will end up with garbage values.

Dealing correctly with denominator / numerator values greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is difficult.

- The simplest option is use a representation that won't overflow (with your use case); e.g. `BigInteger` but that also is limited ... by your heap size.
- You can push it further if you are able to find and cancel common factors in the denominator and numerator, but factorization is expensive ... and intractable if the only factors are large primes.)

Comment: ok, so now im creating a new fraction and assigning the value of the method, lather on creating a new matrix an inputing that value on the matrix

Comment: private static Fraccion nueva;
Fraccion[][] nuev = new Fraccion[cuantos][cuantos];
nueva = matrix[i][j].producto_con(tmp[i][j+1]);
                    nuev[i][j] = nueva;

Comment: I create a constructor on my fraction class that receives a fraction and assign it, i dont know if this is correct.

    public Fraccion(Fraccion frac){
        frac = frac;
    }

but i prints 0/0

Comment: No.  It is not correct.  It is assigning the **local variable** `frac` to itself!!

Comment: So, something like this? 
private Fraccion fraccion;
public Fraccion(Fraccion frac){
        fraccion = frac;
    }

Comment: Nope.  You need to explicitly initialize the fields of the `Fraccion` you are creating.  Seriously, I think you need to read a tutorial ... or your textbook.